# Invoking the Activate dialog for sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to invoke the Activate dialog for sheets in a workbook such as below. This dialog can be called manually by right clicking on the arrow button at the bottom left of Excel (2013).

[image]

I tried this:

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActivate).Show`

But instead of showing the list of sheets, it shows the list of open workbooks:

[image]

How do I call the Activate dialog for sheets?

Comment: `Application.CommandBars("Workbook tabs").ShowPopup`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks! That's a very nice idea. I could use your suggestion instead. But I'm still curious, is there an answer to the question?

Comment: that **is** the answer to the question. the code I posted **is** the way ... the only, AFAIK.

Comment: It is not a dialog box it is a command bar.

Comment: @Davesexcel do you know how to call it ?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman ..comment is the solution, it's not a dialog box, it is a command bar.

Comment: @Davesexcel - Yes, I was trying to say there is **no** dialog box that will show the worksheet list in a pop-up window.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman- Yep, I was just explaining that to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to show the Sheet Command bar:

```
Sub ShowSheets()
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook tabs").ShowPopup
End Sub
```

[image]

<sub>Content salvaged from comments by [Scott Holtzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman) and [Davesexcel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392235/davesexcel).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own dialog box if you want. Create a userForm and populate it with the names of the Worksheets upon activation. You can see what the user selected through the selected function, e.g.

```
ListBox1.Selected(i)
```

You can then call a sub with the name of the Sheet and activate it, e.g.

```
Sub ChangeSheet(SheetName)
    Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for idea and i already have a uf for this. but i don't want to maintain it, so i can just use the ready made one from microsoft.